# PHP Regex - Remove a specific string after certain pattern

Tags: php, regex

I'm making column shortcodes in WordPress and it always add `</p>` after the tag.

So the raw HTML result from dumping the variable looks like this:

```
<column class="size-5"></p>
....
</column>
```

I want to delete that lone `</p>` with regex, so I made this:

```
$content = preg_replace("/(?!<column[^<]+)<\/p>/", '', $content);
```

I matched`</p>` while excluding the column tag. Here's the [Regexr link](http://regexr.com/3ehvj).

In regexr (which I assume uses JS syntax), it works perfectly. But in PHP, it matches every single `</p>` and remove it.

I have tried many variation for look behind `?<!` and `?>!` but doesn't work.

Has anyone experienced this same problem before?

Thanks

Comment: Does it mean you only need to remove the first match? (You did not activate `/g` modifier at regexr). You know, `preg_replace` has a *$limit* argument, you may set it to `1`. And to tell the truth, `(?!<column[^<]+)<\/p>` is a wrong pattern as `(?!<column[^<]+)` here will always be true since `</p>` is not `<col`. I feel you wanted to use a lookbehind, but PCRE does not support an infinite width lookbehind patterns.

Comment: Try `$content = preg_replace('/(<column[^<]*>)<\/p>/', '$1', $content);`

Comment: I want to match every `</p>` after `<column>` not only the first one. I see, so in Regexr also behaves like that with `/g`. Is there any other way to do this? I think it's quite a common use case

Comment: It is an extemely frequent kind of regex question, and there are a lot of ways to do it: `$content = preg_replace('/(<column[^<]*>)<\/p>/', '$1', $content);` or `$content = preg_replace('/<column\b[^<]*>\s*\K<\/p>/', '', $content);`, etc.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes! that works perfectly. Thanks. You can write an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should know that manipulating HTML with regex is vulnerable and may not work in 100% cases with arbitrary HTML code. You should only use it when you know what you are doing (you generate the HTML yourself in the unique way, or the HTML provider is known and uses a unqiue approach to HTML escaping, etc.).

Next, you do not need to use any negative lookaheads. The pattern you are using matches any `</p>` that is not a starting subsequence of `<column[^<]+` subpattern, which is always true, and you effectively match *any* `</p>`.

*In case you want to remove some text that appears in some specific known context*, you may rely on *capturing* what you need and *just matching* what you want to replace. The only thing to do is to enclose the part of pattern you will need to keep with `(...)` and use  a backreference to that group in the replacement pattern.

Use

```
$content = preg_replace('/(<column\b[^<]*>)<\/p>/', '$1', $content);
```

Alternatively, in PCRE, you may use `\K` operator that omits the whole text matched so far like

```
$content = preg_replace('/<column\b[^<]*>\s*\K<\/p>/', '', $content);
```

And you won't have to use any backreferences in the replacement pattern.

I added the `\b` (word boundary) to make sure `column` is matched as a whole word. Since it still can match `column` in `column-editor`, you might want to repace `<column\b[^<]*>` with `<column(?:\s[^<]*)?>`.

Comment: Thanks for the detail. Will consider it

Comment: I added another hint. If you can guarantee there are no `column-editor` like tags, and no `<` inside attribute values, this will work. In other cases, write a longer regex to account for attribute-value pairs inside single-, double- and no quotes. Something like `<column(?:\s+[^\s=]+(?:=(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|\S+))?)*>`